# ¿Por qué algo "patillero" es algo poco elaborado, cutre?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, coloquialismos, españa

Con frecuencia, en ambientes informales, se califica en España algo de "patillero" cuando es poco elaborado, falto de rigor:

> Hay quien dice que la tierra es cuadrada porque el horizonte es recto.
>   A mí me parece un poco patillero
>
> Juan llegó tarde a clase y dijo que se había dormido. A mí me sonó
>   algo patillero, pues una hora antes lo había visto por la calle.

Buscando en la RAE no encuentro referencias a la palabra y "patilla" no parece tener ninguna acepción que se asemeje a lo aquí expuesto. Me pregunto pues: ¿qué origen tiene esta expresión? ¿se usa en algún otro lugar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la versión electrónica de la 23.ª edición del [«*Diccionario de la lengua española*»](http://dle.rae.es/)

> [**el patillas,** o **patillas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S9aegsW#8NaAI2T)
>
> 1. m. p. us. *El diablo (príncipe de los ángeles rebelados).*

Buscando por Google encontré este libro: *Cuento tradicional, cultura, literatura (siglos XVI-XIX) By Máxime Chevalier*

> El demonio tiene pies -o patas- disformes: es el «patituerto» que dice el capigorrón *Penuria* en *El casamiento por Cristo*, el «ángel patudo» que dice el gracioso *Cosme* de *La dama duende*.
>
> De tal desgracia se originan cantidad de apodos que llueven menudos sobre el demonio. «Pateta» y «Patillas» quedan registrados por los diccionarios; «Pateta», pronuncia el Diccionario de Autoridades, es «apodo que se da al cojo o que tiene algún pie o pierna tuerta, o encogida»; «Patillas», según el mismo diccionario, es «nombre que vulgarmente se da al demonio, sin duda porque comúnmente le pintan con unos pies o patas muy disformes y feas».

¿Su uso actual? Me parece una evolución de este significado.

Cabe decir que solo había oído patillas en el lenguaje coloquial para referirse a alguien que parece tener malas intenciones (¿pequeño demonio?), pero no con el que mencionas en tu pregunta que coincide con los explicado en el libro.

Answer (score 1):

La palabra **patillero** no está registrada en el Diccionario.

Esa palabra no se utiliza en México hasta donde yo sé, pero mejor utiliza una palabra que sea "Universal", no suena mejor **"creíble"** ?:

> Hay quien dice que la tierra es cuadrada porque el horizonte es recto. A mí me parece poco creíble
>
> Juan llegó tarde a clase y dijo que se había dormido. A mí me sonó poco creíble, pues una hora antes lo había visto por la calle.

creíble
Del lat. credibĭlis.
1. adj. Que puede o merece ser creído.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Nótese que pajillero es algo completamente diferente : ) En cuanto a la respuesta en sí, agradezco la recomendación de alternativas. Sin embargo, mi pregunta versa sobre el origen de la expresión, no sobre cómo decirlo en otro contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser tal vez una deformación inintencionada de **pacotillero** y **pacotilla**, palabras que sí se relacionan con lo poco fino.

> **[ser de pacotilla algo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RQCpMdm)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Ser de inferior calidad, o estar hecho sin esmero.

Answer (score -1):

NO.

Quiere decir algo cutre, mal hecho, patético.
También se usa para una excusa poco elabaorada (currada):

"Juan llegó tarde a clase y dijo que se había dormido. Una excusa "patillera", pués una hora antes lo había visto por la calle.

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta. ¿Por qué empizas con un "NO"? Intenta [edit]arla para que sea más entendible. Gracias y bienvenido/a a [spanish.se].